# How to convert IChangeSet<int> to List<int>?

Tags: c#, wpf, reactive-programming

I need to convert `IObservable<int>` to `IObservable<bool>`. To do this I need in last two values of `observableSelectedQuantity`.

```
    IObservable<int> observableSelectedQuantity;
    public Constructor()
    {
        observableSelectedQuantity = Item.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedQuantity);
        observableSelectedQuantity.ToObservableChangeSet().Select(ConvertToBool).Subscribe();
    }

    private bool ConvertToBool(IChangeSet<int> arg)
    {
        //Inside logic
    }
```

I thought that I can get last two elements from some kind of list. So I converted `IObservable<int>` to `IChangeSet<int>` and then wrote this code in the `ConvertToBool`:

```
var a = arg.ToList();
```

I expected that each time new element will be added to `observableSelectedQuantity`, `ToList` will generate new list with previous elements plus last one. But every time when new element is added, `ToList()` generate list with only one item which is last element of `observableSelectedQuantity`. Is it possible to solve my problem with `IChangeSet`? Or I need to change my way to get access to list values from `observableSelectedQuantity`?

Answer (score 1):

> I expected that each time new element will be added to `observableSelectedQuantity`, `ToList` will generate new list with previous elements plus last one.

No, it doesn't but you don't need an `IChangeSet<int>` to keep track of the last two values from an `IObservable<int>`. You could just store the previous value in a variable, e.g.:

```
IObservable<int> observableSelectedQuantity = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedQuantity);
IObservable<bool> observableOfBools = observableSelectedQuantity.Select(i => ConvertToBool(i));
...
int? previousValue = null;
private bool ConvertToBool(int currentValue)
{
    bool returnValue = ...; //logic

    previousValue = currentValue;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I have understood you. But is it possible to do this without variable which keep previous variable?

Comment: You obviously need to keep track of the value somewhere. An `IObservable<int>` doesn't store values like some kind of list. Why can't you use a variable?

Comment: Because I have list of `Items` which `SelectedProperty` changes I need to listen so I think it won`t be good to store variable for all this items.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Your assumption that "*each time new element will be added to observableSelectedQuantity, ToList will generate new list with previous elements plus last one*" is totally wrong so you need to keep track of this yourself somehow. Where does "a list of Items which SelectedProperty changes" come into this?

Comment: My previous comment is not on our topic. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @AllaevBekzod: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.